# How to increase a value of PHP Variable without page refresh on click event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

The name attribute in input field need to be updated dynamically. The form is being submitted through ajax request and db gets new value, which need to be taken as count increment without page refresh(to save the motive ajax form submit),  How can i increase the PHP count variable..

- I cannot rule out below code coz on first page refresh or any page refresh event it should get the updated value form db,

Will jquery help out and how or some other better method are in your hand.

```
<?PHP
    $sql=sql::readOne("SELECT col_name FROM table_name");
    $sql=json_decode($sql->col_name,true);
    $count= count($sql);
?>
```

HTML CODE PART

```
 </form>
        ..... 
        <input class="form-control" name="col_name[<?php echo $count+1 ?>][username]" placeholder="User Name" type="text" id="username" value="" >
  <input class="form-control" name="col_name[<?php echo $count+1 ?>][email]" placeholder="email" type="text" id="email" value="" >
        .....
        <button type="submit"  id="editdata" class="btn btn-success">Edit and Update </button>
    </form>
```

Comment: What is your atual purpose to increment the value?

Comment: I need to collect the form values in myarray[col_name][$i][name_attribute]  and my json data in db is sth like this {"1":{"username":"Paul","email":"paul@abc.com"},"2":{"username":"Joshua","email":"abc@bbc.com"}}. I am submitting the form via ajax and if the user hits another addition through form the previous data gets updated instead of incrementing the third value

Comment: can it be done through ajax on successful form submission, means updating all values through some way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update your database immediately using ajax after php increments a variable, so that when your page reloads, it gets the incremented value in the database.

Comment: please read my abve comment that might help you get the actual idea

Comment: all you have to do is update or insert data to your database. Where is your other query?